# Java set properties by string key

Tags: java

Is there any libraries that help with setting a field on an object by giving the path to the field. For example if I had the following string

```
classroom.students[3].address[1].state=VA
```

it would parse the string and do the following

```
classroom.getStudents().get(3).getAddress().get(1).setState("VA")
```

I'm sure it wouldn't be too difficult to write a method to do this using reflection, but I don't want to recreate the wheel if such a method already exists in Apache Commons or something.

Comment: XPath, Expression Language.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks. [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) was what I needed